# GNOME hangs after upgrade

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I upgraded Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04. Shortly after that, GNOME has been hanging.

I started with a 4x4 grid of workspaces. After navigating the workspaces for a little while, the 4x4 grid changes to a 1x16 array. Then, I can't type in any windows, move the windows, navigate between windows, or navigate between workspaces.

I CAN access the command bar at the top. I tried opening Settings. It opens, but I can't interact with anything inside the window or even close it.

Any idea of what's wrong?

```
% ls -l ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions (all are 755)
    ./
    ../
    alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com/
    apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/
    desktop-icons@csoriano/
    drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    emacsmanager@localvoid.gmail.com/
    gnome-shell-trash-extension/
    hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca/
    launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    LogOutButton@kyle.aims.ac.za/
    native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    show-ip@sgaraud.github.com/
    sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net/
    Static_Workspaces@rmy.pobox.com/
    suspend-button@laserb/
    system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com/
    TopIcons@phocean.net/
    user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/
    wsmatrix@martin.zurowietz.de/
```

Comment: You probably have a bad GNOME extension. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily turn them ALL OFF, except `Ubuntu AppIndicators` and `Ubuntu Dock`. Restart gnome-shell with alt-f2, r, enter. See if the machine behaves as normal. If so, go back and turn on one extension at a time, testing each one as you go. If it gets a RED error button beside the name, it's not compatible. If it doesn't work as expected, it's not compatible. Report back.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and I'll see if I recognize any bad extensions.